# Obtaining the minimum number of tails of coin after flipping the entire row or column multiple times

Tags: algorithm

If coins are placed on a grid and only an entire row or column can be flipped, how can we flip the coins to obtain the minimum number of tails.

I tried to using the greedy solution, in which I flip the row or column where the number of tails are greater than heads and repeat the process until there exists no change on the number. But I found that this approach does not give me an optimal solution in some times.

```
HHT
THH
THT
```

For example, if the coins are placed like the above and I flip the coins in below manner, the obtained value is 3 but actually the answer is 2.

```
1. Flip the row 3
HHT
THH
HTH
2. Then there exists no row or column where the number of tails are greater than that of heads.
3. But if I flip the column 3, row 3, column 1, there exists a solution whose value is 2.
THH
HHT
HHH
```

So, I think the above algorithm doesn't work. What approach and what algorithm should I use?

Comment: Why would the answer be 2? Why do you terminate once there is now row/column with more T than H, can't you flip until everything is heads? If by flip you really mean conduct the stochastic experiment of flipping all coins, you are more likely to end up with a non-optimal solution than with an optimal one.

Comment: @G.Bach I think that in his case coins are simply tokens that can either show tails or heads, and flipping simply means that the coin is turned over.

Comment: @Svalorzen You are right. I think I used the word wrong.. What I mean was just switching head and tail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let us notice that there is no point in flipping the same row or column twice or more (a better solution is always either flipping the row/column zero or one time), and the order we flip the rows or columns is irrelevant, so we can describe a solution as a bit array of length 2N.  One bit per row and one bit per column.  On if we flip that row/column once, off if we flip it zero times.

So we need to search 2^(2N) possible solutions, prefering solutions with more zeros.

Secondly let us notice that for one solution there are four possible states of a coin:

1. The coin was not flipped (0 flips)
2. The coin was flipped by its row (1 flip)
3. The coin was flipped by its column (1 flip)
4. The coin was flipped by both its row and column (2 flips)

Notice that state 1 and 4 result in the original value of the coin

Also notice that state 2 and 3 result in the opposite of the original value of the coin

Start by expressing the original state of the coins as a binary matrix (B).  The 2N-bit field as 2 binary vectors (R, C), and the total number of tails as a function of this f(B, R, C), and the total number of bits as a function g(`V_1`, `V_2`)

So your goal is to make f >= minimum while minimizing g.

Think that if we first fix our R configuration (which rows we will flip), how can we solve the problem just for C (which columns we will flip)?  Put another way, consider the simpler problem of only being allowed to flip columns, and not being allowed to flip rows.  How would you solve this? (hint: DP)  Can you extend this stategy back to the full problem now?

Comment: I don't really see how considering a fixed row-vector helps understand how DP can be applied here. If we fix which rows we flip, then greedily flipping columns with more T than H will work, or am I missing something?

Comment: @G.Bach: Yes, actually greedily flipping would work to solve the simpler fixed row problem, however that is not the solution I am hinting at.

Comment: I've been thinking about this problem quite a bit and still can't see how to do it; could you give a more specific hint as to how to use DP for this? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the complete algorithm, but one thing you should definitely try exploit here are the large number of symmetries in your problem.

A lot of different coin configurations will actually be equivalent, so you can rotate, mirror your configuration without altering the problem. Most importantly, since you can reverse the whole set by flipping all rows, looking for the minimum number of tails is equivalent to looking for the minimum number of heads.

In your case, it would be

```
HHT
THH
THT

HTT
TTH
TTT
```

By flipping the middle column, and you're done (you then have to flip everything of course if you really need it).

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution is to try all possibilities of flipping a row or a column. There are `O(2^(2N))` such possibilities. However, we can solve the problem in `O(N^2 * 2^N)` with a combination of greedy + brute force.

Generate all possibilities of flipping the rows (`O(2^N)`) and for each of these, flip each column that has more tails than heads. Take the solution that gives you the minimum tails.

This should work. I will add more details about why a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound, alternately considering new vertical lines and new horizontal lines. There is also some symmetry you can remove - if you flip all the horizontal lines and all the vertical line, you will end up back where you started, so with branch and bound you might as well arbitrarily assume that the leftmost vertical line is never flipped.

```
HHT
THH
THT
```

In this example, if we assume that the leftmost vertical line is not flipped, then if we branch on the lowest horizontal line we know the value of the leftmost lowest coin, so we have two possible partial solutions - one in which that single known coin is fixed at tails, and one in which it is fixed at heads. If we recurse first to try and extend the partial solution in which the single known coin is heads and find that we can extend this to a solution that produces no tails, then we can discard all the partial solutions produced by extending the other, because all its descendants must have at least one tail.

I would next branch on the leftmost but one vertical line, which will give us another known coin, and continue branching alternately horizontally and vertically.

This will be a feasible way of finding an exact solution if there is a nearly perfect solution or if the table is very small. Otherwise you will have to stop it early or have it skip credible solutions to get the problem finished in a reasonable time, and you will probably not get the exact best answer.